# how can i add ssl at my web server with nginx certbot?

Tags: ssl, nginx, certbot

I'm adding ssl on my web server.
I'm using django, nginx, uwsgi.
I got ssl key from certbot, letsencrypt.
but when i adding ssl key path at .conf, it won't work..
what is wrong with my code?
this is nginx.conf

```
#user  nobody;
#Defines which Linux system user will own and run the Nginx server

worker_processes  1;
#Referes to single threaded process. Generally set to be equal to the number of CPUs or cores.

#error_log  logs/error.log; #error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#Specifies the file where server logs.

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;
#nginx will write its master process ID(PID).

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    # worker_processes and worker_connections allows you to calculate maxclients value:
    # max_clients = worker_processes * worker_connections
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    # anything written in /opt/nginx/conf/mime.types is interpreted as if written inside the http { } block

    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    #

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    # If serving locally stored static files, sendfile is essential to speed up the server,
    # But if using as reverse proxy one can deactivate it

    #tcp_nopush     on;
    # works opposite to tcp_nodelay. Instead of optimizing delays, it optimizes the amount of data sent at once.

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    # timeout during which a keep-alive client connection will stay open.

    #gzip  on;
    # tells the server to use on-the-fly gzip compression.

    server {
        # You would want to make a separate file with its own server block for each virtual domain
        # on your server and then include them.
        #tells Nginx the hostname and the TCP port where it should listen for HTTP connections.
        # listen 80; is equivalent to listen *:80;

        server_name  fidochallenge486.tk;
    #server_name localhost;
        # lets you doname-based virtual hosting

       charset utf-8;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            #The location setting lets you configure how nginx responds to requests for resources within the server.
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    server {
        listen       80 ssl;
    listen [::]:80 ssl default_server;
       server_name  fidochallenge486.tk;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/privkey.pem;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
 #  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
       root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }
}
}
```

and this ls path of ssl key from certbot

```
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/privkey.pem
```

http is working but https it not working..
i don't know where is wrong code.
i google all of the blog about nginx certbot ssl but they all different.

Comment: Have you looked at the nginx error log?

Comment: yes i looked error log

Answer (score 0):

can you please update your nginx config as follow

```
server {
    if ($host = fidochallenge486.tk) {
       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    } 


    server_name  fidochallenge486.tk;

    listen 80;
    return 404; 


}



 server{
    server_name fidochallenge486.tk; 
      root         /usr/share/nginx/html or your website location ;

           index index.html index.htm;
          location / {
                      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                }
               
 

        error_page 404 /404.html;
                 location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; 
    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 


}
```

Comment: What you get in ngnix error log. Please post them too.

Comment: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: and i use mac os mojave

Comment: Then check this one https://serverfault.com/q/972146

Comment: http {
    server {
        if ($host = fidochallenge486.tk) {
                return 301 https://fidochallenge486.tk;
        }
        server_name fidochallenge486.tk;
        #listen 80;
        return 404;
    }
    server {
        listen 80; #is equivalent to listen *:80;
        server_name  fidochallenge486.tk;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        charset utf-8;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.html;
        }

Comment: error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
                root html;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on;
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    }
}

Comment: Same error you got.? Or different error in nginx error log file?

Comment: 2020/07/19 03:07:59 [notice] 40834#0: signal process started
2020/07/19 03:07:59 [emerg] 5335#0: cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:fopen('/etc/letsencrypt/live/fidochallenge486.tk/fullchain.pem','r') error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib)